# How can I change the order template engines are used in Rails 3.0.10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb, slim-lang

Given I have the view templates **index.html.erb** ,**index.html.haml** and **index.html.slim** in the same directory. How can I configure Rails to first use the slim templates if present, then the haml template and last the erb template?

Comment: Why would you have multiple templates? Use one (e.g. index.html.slim) and if you really need the other just rename them to "index_html.html" etc. you would need to configure their usage anyway.

Comment: I'm converting from erb to slim and I've been renaming the erb templates as I go, but I just got curious whether this could be done at all. I couldn't find such an option from the docs nor google.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to create a PathResolver that used something other than key order to get the actual file (FileSystemResolver is the default; see action_view/template/resolver.rb; see action_view/template/handlers.rb for the key-order thing I'm referring to). This is unverified, though; sorry :(

I'm not sure how to tell Rails to *use* a new implementation, though (assuming not just monkey-patching). Using a custom view resolver is as easy as calling append_view_path in the controller class, but I'm not sure if that makes sense for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works in older Rails, but in Rails 7 handlers are prioritized in the order they are registered. You can re-register a handler so it's prioritized last. For example to move ERB to last priority:

```rb
ActionView::Template.unregister_template_handler(:erb)
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(
  :erb, ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB.new)
```

To do the same with haml:

```rb
ActionView::Template.unregister_template_handler(:haml)
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(
  :haml, Haml::RailsTemplate.new)
```

More generally, if you search through a gem for `register_template_handler`, then you'll likely find the handler you need to register.

You could put that code in an initializer or perhaps only run it if a query string is present.